Existence and uniqueness of linear recurrence for BCH/RSCODE decoding
I am learning RSCODE decoding. For syndrome decoding, we have linear recurence:
$ S_j \Lambda_v + S_{j+1} \Lambda_{v-1} + ... + S_{j+v-1} \Lambda_v = S_{j+v}  $ for j = 1, 2, ... 2t-v
in which $v$ is the number of errors.
This forms $2t-v$ equations.
In this tutorial P26, we only consider first $v$ equations among $2t-v$ equations. And try $v$ from $t$ to $0$ until the coefficient determinant is non-zero.
I have two questions on that:

if we solved $\{\Lambda\}$ out using the first $v$ equations, is there anything guarantee the remains $2t-2v$ equations also statisfies?

when we find $v$ makes the coefficient determinant non-zero, we can solve out $\{\Lambda\}$. But how to guarantee there are no linear recurence with shorter length (less than $v$)?



No, there is no guarantee that the remaining equations are also satisfied. This phenomenon was studied in the 1990s under the name decoder malfunction (cf. D. V. Sarwate and R. D. Morrison, "Decoder Malfunction in BCH Decoders," IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, pp. 894-899, July 1990, and M. Srinivasan and D. V. Sarwate, "Malfunction in Peterson-Gorenstein-Zierler Decoders" IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, pp. 1649-1653, September 1994.).
